# Styles and bindings acting oddly

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, styles, relativesource

Right. I've got a small program (that replicates my issue). Basically, it tries to bind to some properties of the object it's styling. It **kind of** works: it gives me the default value (from the dependency property). I've been thinking this may be because the `Style`'s `RelativeSource Self` isn't the same as the `TextBox` it's styling's one. But I don't know. I've tried debugging this, checking time and again that the value set in XAML was actually set. The thing is, with a smaller test program it works. This is just a scale up from that. I don't know what's going wrong.
Thanks!

The code for reproducing this issue:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:lcl="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
        Title="My title." Height="350" Width="425" MaxHeight="350" MaxWidth="425" MinHeight="350" MinWidth="425">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="TestDictionary.xaml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxWithDefault}" FontSize="36" lcl:MyOptions.Default="Not default." VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    public static class MyOptions
    {
        public static string GetDefault(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(DefaultProperty);
        }
        public static void SetDefault(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(DefaultProperty, value);
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "Default",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(MyOptions),
                new PropertyMetadata("Default"));
    }
}
```

**TestDictionary.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:lcl="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxWithDefault">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=(lcl:MyOptions.Default), Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                       Foreground="LightGray"
                                       FontSize="{Binding Path=(FontSize), Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" x:Key="TheLabel"/>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <VisualBrush AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="None" Visual="{DynamicResource TheLabel}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <VisualBrush AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="None" Visual="{DynamicResource TheLabel}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have no idea what's going wrong here, as a scaled down version of this works **perfectly.** There's probably something I overlooked, that will seem pretty obvious when I find it. But I can't find it now.

EDIT: Well, it seems I was dumb. The original version ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253650/how-to-make-a-wpf-resource-be-recalculated-when-a-triggers-run)) uses a `Trigger`, which means that it gets the parent textbox's value. The question now is: how can I get it working?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: `RelativeSource Self` will just be the `Label` in this case, so you won't get the `TextBox`' value that way. Could you post the code that actually works?

Comment: @Sphinxxx it was in another question and when I saw it I figured out why: its in a setter. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253650/how-to-make-a-wpf-resource-be-recalculated-when-a-triggers-run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real show-stopper here is that when you use the `Label` in a `VisualBrush`, the label isn't part of the `TextBox`' ["Visual Tree"](http://wpftutorial.net/LogicalAndVisualTree.html) (see for example Sheldon Xiao's answer to this similar question on MSDN: [Binding Problem inside VisualBrush](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5924fa47-c272-4d25-b416-2a2da18a68ce/binding-problem-inside-visualbrush)).

This means that the label won't inherit the text box' `DataContext`, and you can't reach the text box from a `RelativeSource` binding either. In contrast, the accepted answer in your other post sets the actual content of a button, which *does* make the content part of the button's visual tree.

So I don't think there's a pure XAML solution to this problem - pushing the correct `MyOptions.Default` from the text box to the label. One possible code-based solution is to scrap the `TextBoxWithDefault` style and do everything from your attached property when `Default` changes:

```
...
public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Default",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(MyOptions),

        //Listen for changes in "Default":
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnMyDefaultChanged));

private static void OnMyDefaultChanged(DependencyObject sender, 
                                       DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var text = (TextBox)sender;
    var myDefault = e.NewValue;

    var defaultLabel = new Label();
    defaultLabel.Foreground = Brushes.LightGray;

    //Explicitly bind the needed value from the TextBox:
    defaultLabel.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty,
                            new Binding()
                            {
                                Source = text,
                                Path = new PropertyPath(MyOptions.DefaultProperty)
                            });

    text.Background = new VisualBrush()
    {
        Visual = defaultLabel,
        AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left,
        AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Center,
        Stretch = Stretch.None
    };
    text.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(OnTextWithDefaultChanged);
}

private static void OnTextWithDefaultChanged(object sender, 
                                             TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var text = (TextBox)sender;
    var defaultLabel = (text.Background as VisualBrush).Visual as Label;

    defaultLabel.Visibility = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text.Text) ? 
                                                Visibility.Visible : 
                                                Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll go for this if nothing else gets said but I'd rather not break MVVM if I could.

Comment: Yes, I'd welcome a cleaner solution too, but this way of doing things is actually quite common (and still ok for MVVM). It even has a fancy name: [Attached _Behavior_](http://eladm.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/attached-behavior/)

Comment: I've got a kludge, but I'm not quite sure... hopefully it'll be fine (`TemplateBinding`... now the question is how to get all the properties of the `TextBox` to automatically attach to it)

Comment: In that case, you're looking at creating a brand new `ControlTemplate` for you text boxes (not only a `Style`). That might work. In that case, this other SO post is slightly related to yours: [Custom template for a TextBox ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751990/how-to-change-disabled-background-color-of-textbox-in-wpf)

Comment: I'm doing that. The only problem is setting all the properties manually is a pain... so I stopped and I'm now looking for a better way.